# Call function from Child and not parent class C#

Tags: c#, .net, inheritance, console

I'm making a rendering engine in the .NET Console, and for that purpose I've built the structure up with an Inherited RenderObject.

This RenderObject is a class that stores all Rendering Information for the object that inherits this. For example, X, Y coordinates, Width and Height etc.

I'm trying to do the following. But it instead calls the Render function from the RenderObject (Inherited Object) instead of the child objects.

How do I achieve this? Calling the Childs render function and not the Parents render function.

Thanks!

**Renderer:**

```
class Renderer {

    public List<RenderObject> RenderObjects { get; }

    public Renderer()
    {
        RenderObjects = new List<RenderObject>();

        AddRenderObject(new RenderText());
        AddRenderObject(new RenderBox());
    }

    public void AddRenderObject(RenderObject ro)
    {
        RenderObjects.Add(ro);
    }

    public void Draw()
    {
        foreach(RenderObject ro in RenderObjects)
        {
            ro.Render(); //This should call the function from RenderText and RenderBox
        }
    }
}
```

**Parent Class (The Class that can be inherited)**

```
class RenderObject
{
    public int X;
    public int Y;
    public int Width;
    public int Height;

    public void Render()
    {
       //This should NOT be called
    }
}
```

**Child objects that inherits RenderObject**

```
class RenderBox : RenderObject
{
    public void Render()
    {
        //This should be called
    }
}

class RenderText : RenderObject
{
    public void Render()
    {
        //This should be called
    }
}
```

Comment: You should read https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9fkccyh4.aspx. See marked duplicate for additional details as to why you are required to use `virtual` to achieve the behavior you want.

Comment: Maybe you should override the Render method with public new void Render?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should mark it as `virtual` and override them in the child classes

```
class RenderObject
{
    public int X;
    public int Y;
    public int Width;
    public int Height;

    public virtual void Render()
    {
       //This should NOT be called
    }
}

class RenderBox : RenderObject
{
    public override void Render()
    {
        //This should be called
    }
}

class RenderText : RenderObject
{
    public override void Render()
    {
        //This should be called
    }
}
```

Comment: This is exactly it. I've never heard of the keyword "Virtual", but now that I do, this makes so much more sense! Thanks!